# New baby wishes

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

Is it correct to say:

> *Vous venez de gagner une double dose d'amour !
>
>   Qu'ils vous comblent de joie et de bonheur pour toujours !*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're writing to someone with twin babies, and this is overall correct. If anything, it's just slightly unusual for the "gagner une [...] dose" part, but not shocking in itself, and maybe more original. I would say go for it.